# My site's Alexa rank got worse and Alexa stopped ranking some sub-domains

Tags: ranking, alexa

I have a website which has reached an Alexa rank of 250,000.  It had four sub-domains and Alexa was ranking them as well.

Two weeks ago, my rank became 290,000 and Alexa now shows only one sub-domain in addition to the main domain.

I use the Alexa toolbar and all my friends use it. I would at least think that Alexa should rank a sub-domain which we use everyday.  Why did this happen?

Comment: Alexa is junk metrics data and does weird things. Do not be surprised by anything Alexa does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexa ranks vary all the time.  Here is what the Stack Exchange rank looks like according to Alexa's own graph.   As you can see, it goes down and it comes up.   These types of changes happen.

[image]

Alexa typically does not rank subdomains at all.  Even a very popular subdomain like webmasters.stackexchange.com doesn't get a special ranking compared to the parent site: http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/webmasters.stackexchange.com

You appear to by trying to game Alexa's ranking by having you and your friends install the toolbar.   As far as I am concerned, this is pointless.   The only advantage to having a better Alexa rank is bragging rights.    A better rank doesn't direct extra visitors to your site, or help your site make money.